# hypothesis testing dependent proportions /repeated mesurements proportions

Tags: testing, statistics

I need statistical advice:

I have two groups, e.g. young (N=57) and old adults (N=61), and 4 sights in a city. The task for all participants was to visit either one, two, three or all four sights in the city.

The result is a frequency table of how many participants visited the four sites.

```
       Sight 1      Sight 2         Sight 3         Sight 4
Old     80%         45%             33%             45%
Young   78%         60%             30%             42%
```

I would like to test 1) sights were visited in similar proportions across the participant groups and 2) whether the proportion of participants visiting each sight was higher/lower in old people.

Looking at the table, I would expect that the sights visited are equally distributed across the groups meaning that Sight 1 has been visited by both groups more than Sights 2-4. Also I would expect that the proportion of young people that visted sight 2 is higher compared to old people.
How would I test this?

I thought about a chi-square test but the as the participants can visit one or more sights the sample is not independent, this test seems not appropriate. Also, I would like to avoid the multiple testing problem as much as possible.

Thanks

Comment: If you have information about which individual visit which sight, then you can do a logistic regression to infer the proportions you are interested in.

Comment: I would suggest you focus your question on how to code and test for this, otherwise maybe posting in Since SO is more about programming, you can post your question in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions gets you a more generic answer

Comment: I will have a look into logistic regression and will post my question in the other forum as you suggested. Thanks!